# Не могу получить ссылку на скачку видео(Youtube)

Tags: php, youtube

Не могу получить ссылку на скачку некоторых видео с ютуба https://www.youtube.com/get_video_info?video_id=$id

Например для id = y2tEPmwWEiI отдает пустой url_encoded_fmt_stream_map. В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: скорее всего это зависит от самого видеоролика (вы попробуйте http://ssyoutube.com/watch?v=y2tEPmwWEiI) там всего 2 формата mp4 (360) и  WebM (720) тогда как на других ссылках хватает и других форматов, а бывает что нет и этого... это скорее вопрос к разработчикам страницы get_video_info. я как-то искал тоже не нашел и пришел к этому выводу (хотя могу ошибаться и есть другие объяснения этому явлению)

Comment: да, зависит от ролика. я смог получить ссылки и для этого видео, но они отдают 403. нет прав доступа. Я читал о кодировке сигнатуры, но я так и ничего не понял :)